# Want Start Call by Clicking Bluetooth Button, But unable to get sound on web end Vonage Ios

Tags: ios, vonage

We are working on a lone-worker safety app in which we want to start a call by clicking Bluetooth button, its working fine when app is open but when app is in background call is started but no sound listen on web end.